# Django, splitting a filter into separate links

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a sort of an invoice system and I've created a model with the ForeignKey as the user. I made a custom view where I filter invoices by the current user. I need the filter to actually separate the invoices so I can create links to the actual invoice. Query and loop is my first instinct, but I just can't figure out how to do this in Django.

```
# models.py
class invoice(models.Model):
    date            = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    bill_to         = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    service         = models.CharField(max_length="50", choices=serviceChoice, default='')
    price           = models.CharField(max_length="3"

# views.py
def invoicelist(request):
    current_user = request.user
    current_user = current_user.id
    p =list(invoice.objects.filter(bill_to=current_user))

    return render_to_response('invoice-list.html', {'invoice':p})
```

I call {{ invoice }} in invoice-list.html and it's a list of ALL invoices. If I try to use a for loop, it just lists the entire list over and over. I need them to be linkable to the appropriate invoice. Part of me feels like I'm going about this all wrong.

Comment: what is in your database in the `APPNAME_invoice` table for `bill_to`?

Comment: are all your bill_to persons also users on your system? if not, it would make more sense to put them in a seperate model/table

Comment: please follow standard naming convention. Capitalize for class name

Comment: Why are you settting `current_user` twice btw? Remove the second one, and use `bill_to=current_user.id` in your filter.

Comment: @RickyA the bill_to pulls from all users in my system. Should I instead create a custom model and filter by something in that model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [`get_absolute_url()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url)

```
<!-- File: invoice-list.html -->
{% for invoice in invoices %}
    <a href="{{ invoice.get_absolute_url }}">{{ invoice.id }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

---

*Note: Correction for your `models.py` & `views.py`:*

```
# File: models.py
class Invoice(models.Model):
    date            = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    bill_to         = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    service         = models.CharField(max_length="50", choices=serviceChoice, default='')
    price           = models.CharField(max_length="3"

# File: views.py
def invoice_list(request):
    current_user = request.user.id
    invoices = Invoice.objects.filter(bill_to=current_user)
    return render_to_response('invoice-list.html', {'invoices':invoices})
```

---

### Alternative (Optional):

You can also consider using url reverse. For example:

```
<!-- File: invoice-list.html -->
{% for invoice in invoices %}
    <a href="{% url 'invoice-detail' invoice.id %}">{{ invoice.id }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Provided you have the url configured correctly, for example:

```
# File: urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^invoices/$', views.invoice_list, name='invoice-list'),
    url(r'^invoice/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.invoice_detail, name='invoice-detail'),
]
```